# Jquery SerializeArray and Push Object list

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, serialization, serializearray

I'am SerializeArray using and try to push object list but always is null on server side

```
var $form = $('#personelReqForm');
var model = $form.serializeArray();

  model.Leavemembers = [],
  model.MemberLanguages = [];


            $.map($('#tblLeaveingMember tbody tr[data-id="0"]'),
                function(obj) {
                    model.LeaveMembers.push({
                            MembershipId: $(obj).attr('data-mid'),
                            LeavingDate: $(obj).attr('data-date')

                    });


                });
```

end of model View..

```
    (16) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, LeaveMembers: Array(1), MemberLanguages: Array(0)]
    0: {name: "Id", value: "0"}
    1: {name: "TitleId", value: ""}
    2: {name: "CompanyCardId", value: "2"}
    3: {name: "DepartmentId", value: "175"}
    4: {name: "ReasonId", value: "94"}
    5: {name: "ContractTypeId", value: ""}
    6: {name: "PersonnelGroupId", value: ""}
    7: {name: "MembershipLevelId", value: ""}
    8: {name: "TargetedStartDate", value: "24.10.2019"}
    9: {name: "StationId", value: ""}
    10: {name: "LanguageId", value: ""}
    11: {name: "LanguageLevelId", value: ""}
    12: {name: "Keywords", value: "<p><br></p>"}
    13: {name: "Certificates", value: "<p><br></p>"}
    14: {name: "ComputerSkills", value: "<p><br></p>"}
    15: {name: "Description", value: "<p><br></p>"}
    LeaveMembers: Array(1)
    0: {MembershipId: "172024", LeavingDate: "24.10.2019"}
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

How can ı send all objects with ajax? Thank u..

Comment: Where you send all objects like eg MVC application or something else?

Answer (score 0):

First I wrote mini code for array to json

```
  function arrayToJSON(array) {
            var _ = {};

            $.map(array,
                function(obj) {
                    _[obj.name] = obj.value;

                });
            return _;
        }

 var modelJSONobj = arrayToJSON(model);
```

and other two object List Leavemembers = [{}],
  MemberLanguages = [{}];

extend them to JsonObject

 `var dat = $.extend(modelJSONobj ,{ LeaveMembers: LeaveMembers });
            dat = $.extend(dat, { MemberLanguages: MemberLanguages });`